# How to simulate a clicking visual effect when clicking on a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, animation, jbutton, jlabel

I have a JLabel (sorry I can't have a JButton) and a mouse listener to trap the click. All I need now is to simulate some kind of clicking visual effect/animation. This seems complicated because repaints are asynchronous. How do I go about doing that???

Answer (score 2):

Use a MouseListener.

1. On mousePressed() you set a Border
2. On mouseReased() you reset the Border.

Comment: This won't work because repaints are asynchronous. Try for yourself.

Comment: @chrisapotek Between a mouse press and mouse release, the event thread is still running and processing events...it'd kind stupid if it didn't :P

Comment: It works fine (how do you think a JButton works?). Post your `SSCCE` demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I may be wrong, but I thought that setting the border does nothing until you call repaint. So to actually implement a predictable animation, one has to use paintImmediately.

Comment: @chrisapotek Even if you had to `repaint` on mouse press, the event queue would be capable of processing the the request...but you don't, it's a bound property, meaning Swing will respond to it automatically...Now imagine if the EDT stopped responding when the mouse was clicked, how would drag and drop work?

Comment: @chrisapotek, `but I thought that setting the border does nothing until you call repaint.` - don't think. Try it. Two people have asked you to try it. When you ask for help and get an answer, then try the suggestion before assuming it won't work.

Comment: by the way if this question is related to your last question, this approach still won't solve your problem, because like the last question states a renderer is not a real component so you are not clicking on the label like you think you are.